# Distinguish Windows services with the same ProcessName

Tags: powershell, memory, windows-services, monitoring, powershell-3.0

I am adjusting a monitoring system which checks if a service is running or not. It does that by checking the process name and it's memory consumption. Once it drops below 1 MB an alert is triggered. Also I use the memory usage value to display it in a graph. So checking and notifying is not the only purpose.

Currently I have 5 Windows services using the same `ProcessName` and I don't know how to make my script distinguish them. The `ServiceName` for each service is of course different and the path to the executable as well. 
When I run `get-process` I see them all, but I don't see an option here distinguish them. Using `get-service` doesn't help much either, because it returns name, displayed name and status. Somehow I would love to combine the entries to see the memory usage by service name, not by process name.

Comment: You'll need to do two queries. Look at using `win32_service` WMI object. That will list the corresponding process names and PIDs of the services which you can then use in a `get-process` command

Comment: that sounds good, thank you arco444

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say that the path to executable is different - this way you can distinguish the processes by querying `path` property. Should they be equal, you can also query `StartInfo` object of a process to get `Arguments` property to discern from one another. But the best way to get correct process instances will be to query WMI objects of type `Win32_Service` to filter your services out, this way you can find if one of them is stopped as well, and then get the process by passing the `ProcessId` property of the WMI service object. For running services, the PID will be valid. An example (which only filters by service name):

```
gwmi win32_service | ? {$_.name -eq "wsearch"} | % {get-process -id $_.processid}
```

Note that there is a possibility that one process will handle more than a single service, this is called "Shared service process" and is visible in `Get-Service` output as `ServiceType` property of the returned service, the value `Win32SharedProcess` (0x20) indicated the underlying PID can be shared, although it's not always the case. The most known shared service process is `svchost.exe` which also has a sort of a namespace to determine which process should host a certain service, passed to it as a command line parameter.